# Get ProjectItem path without using item.Document.FullName

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, envdte

I have a visual studio add-in project where I must iterate through the current project's items, utilizing the absolute (or relative) path to those files.

The `item.Document.FullName` works, but only for files that are currently opened.

Is there any other way to access this information in the `DTE` object?

Answer (score 26):

Is this what you're looking for?

```cs
myProjectItem.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value
```

Comment: And this link has some more specific info about what is contained in the properties list for a ProjectItem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228957(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Is there any list of properties?

Answer (score 4):

Even I was looking for a solution to get the project name based on the document or file Name. I found it by using the `DTE` object.
Initialized the `DTE` object like the code shown below.

```cs
EnvDTE80.DTE2 objDTE = this.GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as EnvDTE80.DTE2;
```

Then I used following code, to get the name of the project.

```cs
var projectItem = objDTE.Solution.FindProjectItem(document);
var projectUniqueName = projectItem.ContainingProject.UniqueName;
```

Answer (score 0):

We found that, unless we wanted to parse the XML project files ourselves, you have to first load any unloaded projects.

We record the list and unload them again afterwards so the only issue is the time it takes to load them.

Answer (score 0):

**ProjectItem.FileNames** is a collection that represents the full paths of the associated files

For example if you have webform item called "MyWebForm" you can get from  **ProjectItem.FileNames** the full path of the MyWebForm.ascx file an the full path name of the MyWebForm.ascx.cs (CodeBehind) file