# How to find a ProjectItem by the file name

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, envdte

I'm developing a custom tool for the Visual Studio. The tool is assigned to the file, at the time when the file changed I receive name of this file and should generate some changes in the project. I need to find a ProjectItem by the received file name. I have found only one solution it's enumerate all project items in the each project of the solution. But it seems to be huge solution. Is there a way to get a project item by the file name without enumeration?

This is my implementation of the Generate method of the IVsSingleFileGenerator

```
public int Generate(string sourceFilePath, string sourceFileContent, string defaultNamespace, IntPtr[] outputFileContents, out uint output, IVsGeneratorProgress generateProgress)
{
    var dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));

    ProjectItem projectItem = null;

    foreach (Project project in dte.Solution.Projects)
    {
        foreach (ProjectItem item in project.ProjectItems)
        {
            var path = item.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value;
            if (sourceFilePath.Equals(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                projectItem = item;
            }
        }               
    }

    output = 0;
    outputFileContents[0] = IntPtr.Zero;

    return Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Unclear:  Are you parsing the sln file and then parsing each csproj?  Or are you scanning the file system?

Comment: I'm searching in the DTE object which is provided by the VisualStudio.

Comment: This seems to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38876595/509584

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am using this *user-friendly* world of DTE as well, to create a Guidance. I did not find any better solution. Basically these are methods I am using:

Iterate projects:

```
public static ProjectItem FindSolutionItemByName(DTE dte, string name, bool recursive)
{
    ProjectItem projectItem = null;
    foreach (Project project in dte.Solution.Projects)
    {
        projectItem = FindProjectItemInProject(project, name, recursive);

        if (projectItem != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return projectItem;
}
```

Find in a single project:

```
public static ProjectItem FindProjectItemInProject(Project project, string name, bool recursive)
{
    ProjectItem projectItem = null;

    if (project.Kind != Constants.vsProjectKindSolutionItems)
    {
        if (project.ProjectItems != null && project.ProjectItems.Count > 0)
        {
            projectItem = DteHelper.FindItemByName(project.ProjectItems, name, recursive);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // if solution folder, one of its ProjectItems might be a real project
        foreach (ProjectItem item in project.ProjectItems)
        {
            Project realProject = item.Object as Project;

            if (realProject != null)
            {
                projectItem = FindProjectItemInProject(realProject, name, recursive);

                if (projectItem != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return projectItem;
}
```

The code I am using with more snippets could be found [here](http://catarsa.com/Articles/Download/Catharsis/Any/Catharsis_4_5#download69), as a Guidance for new projects. Search for and take the source code..

Comment: as a warning this doesn't account at all for solution folders. `dteSolution.Projects` returns top level items only, not projects that are in solution folders =(

Comment: I see that this is old, but this really should have the code (or reference) to 'DteHelper.FindItemByName()'.

Comment: The **DteHelper** is not a custom code, but Microsoft - built in. This would be a full name: **`Microsoft.Practices.RecipeFramework.Library.DteHelper`**

Comment: Where can I download the Microsoft.Practices.RecipeFramework.Library ?  thx in advance

Comment: @Jon did you figure out where the library can be found?

Answer (score 2):

May be a little late but use DTE2.Solution.FindProjectItem(fullPathofChangedFile);

Comment: `FindProjectItem(string FileName)` is a member of `EnvDTE._Solution` in `EnvDTE.dll, 8.0.0.0` (i.e. Visual Studio 2005), btw - so you don't need `DTE2`, just `DTE` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

To get project.documents - find an item - use Linq to query files